# Missing L1 cache characteristic

Tags: cpu, cpu-cache

I wrote simple program (with help of Igor Ostrovsky's article 'Gallery of Processor Cache Effects') which supposed to examine levels of cache in my processor. According to Coreinfo provided by Microsoft 
my processor have following levels of cache:

```
+------------------------+---------------+----------+-------------+
| *- Data Cache 0        | Level 1 32 KB | Assoc 8  | LineSize 64 |
| *- Instruction Cache 0 | Level 1 32 KB | Assoc 8  | LineSize 64 |
| -* Data Cache 1        | Level 1 32 KB | Assoc 8  | LineSize 64 |
| -* Instruction Cache 1 | Level 1 32 KB | Assoc 8  | LineSize 64 |
| ** Unified Cache 0     | Level 2 3 MB  | Assoc 12 | LineSize 64 |
+------------------------+---------------+----------+-------------+
```

but if I run:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sz = 256;
    for (size_t s = 0; s < 18; s++)
    {
        std::vector<int> arr(sz, sz);
        int steps = 64 * 1024 * 1024;
        double start = omp_get_wtime();
        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
        {
            arr[(i * 16) % arr.size()]++;
        }
        double end = omp_get_wtime();
        std::cout << "size: " << (4 * sz) / 1024 << "KB\t\t";
        std::cout << "avg time: " << (end - start)*1000000000 / steps << "ns" << std::endl;
        sz *= 2;
    }
}
```

I get following output:

```
size: 1KB               avg time: 4.36752ns
size: 2KB               avg time: 4.27807ns
size: 4KB               avg time: 4.19745ns
size: 8KB               avg time: 3.93159ns
size: 16KB              avg time: 3.95425ns
size: 32KB              avg time: 3.88134ns
size: 64KB              avg time: 3.8112ns
size: 128KB             avg time: 3.60893ns
size: 256KB             avg time: 3.61895ns
size: 512KB             avg time: 3.62264ns
size: 1024KB            avg time: 3.63614ns
size: 2048KB            avg time: 4.34382ns
size: 4096KB            avg time: 24.5113ns
size: 8192KB            avg time: 28.271ns
size: 16384KB           avg time: 28.1093ns
size: 32768KB           avg time: 28.3462ns
size: 65536KB           avg time: 28.2305ns
size: 131072KB          avg time: 28.4871ns
```

Sudden increase in access time between 2048KB and 4096KB is apparent because of L2 3MB cache. But why I don't see any similar increase between 32KB and 64KB because of L1 32KB cache? My processor specification: [link](http://ark.intel.com/products/36500/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7400-3M-Cache-2_80-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB)

Comment: Since you appear to be using only a constant 64B stride, the hardware prefetcher should quickly be trained and accurately prefetch cache blocks.